# I am trying to set up a enquiry form on my vue-bootstrap application but am getting this error when I try to run it

Tags: vuejs2, nodemailer, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to set up my vue application so customers can send emails to a address. My application was working fine but when I installed the firebase, send grid and node mailer packages, this error gets displayed

```
 error  in external "https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js?vue&type=script&lang=js&"

The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script

ERROR in external "https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js?vue&type=script&lang=js&"                                                                                                                                                                   
The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script
 @ ./src/views/Home.vue 2:0-75 3:0-70 3:0-70 10:2-8
 @ ./src/router/index.js 3:0-37 17:13-17
 @ ./src/main.js 4:0-30 12:2-8
```

my main.js file

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import "./registerServiceWorker";
import router from "./router";
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from "bootstrap-vue";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(IconsPlugin);

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css";

new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

I have ran some test emails and they seem to be sending fine, but I can't deploy my application now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should convert your [dynamic](https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports) imports to static like converting this:

```
Import ... from moduleName();
```

To this

```
import ... from 'moduleName':
```

Comment: My code already looks like that. I have just updated the post with my main.js

Comment: ahh In my home.vue it wasn't letting me import a google font using: @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quattrocento+Sans:ital@0;1&display=swap");

Comment: I hope the problem solved now. Good luck in your project.